# How can I pass a gradle property to jib via skaffold

Tags: gradle, skaffold, jib, gradle-properties

I have a gradle build file with the following jib definition:

```
def baseImage = 'ghcr.io/tobias-neubert/eclipse-temurin:17.0.2_8-jre'
jib {
  from {
    image = baseImage
    auth {
      username = githubUser
      password = githubPassword
    }
  }
  to {
    image = 'ghcr.io/tobias-neubert/motd-service:0.0.1'
    auth {
      username = githubUser
      password = githubPassword
    }
  }
}
```

and the following skaffold.yaml:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: motd-service
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: ghcr.io/tobias-neubert/motd-service
      jib:
        args:
          - "-PgithubUser=tobias-neubert"
          - "-PgithubPassword=secret"
manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - k8s/deployment.yaml
    - k8s/istio.yaml
```

It seems that the arguments are not passed to gradle because I get the error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'githubPassword'
```

Why? What am I doing wrong and/or what have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

If I define the property like so:

```
ext {
  githubPassword = System.getProperty('githubPassword', '')
}
```

I have to pass that property as system property vi `-DgithubPassword` not as `-P`